How to change label format of open editors panel in VS Code?
Is it possible to change the label format of the files listed in the "Open Editors" panel on the main sidebar of VS Code?
I know it is possible to change the label format of tabs (Workbench > Editor: Label Format). For example, to show the a shortened path with just the directory name next to file to help projects with lots of 'index' files. I would like to do the same thing to the Open Editors panel
Tab Label Format:

Open Editors:


... weird. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/208388

Just tested that out with "**" set to random text, it successfully changed Open Editors. So, thank you! But unfortunate on the VSCode side is that it overwrites existing tab formatting lol (so it'll show dir twice now), and doesn't let you remove auto-inserted path name from the open editors. I wish the label format settings were more consistent

so.... now what? close this question as not-reproducible? or is your question how to make it consistent? (there's not particularly amazing answer to that- I'm going to guess, other than "open a feature-request issue ticket")

I think that thread you provided would solve it for people searching the same issue. You can post it as an answer or I can post a self-answer once I figure out the exact format. I'm also realizing you can filter it to just index files so that may be helpful

**/index.tsx -> ${dirname}/index

Is this ultimately any different than https://stackoverflow.com/a/78262041/836330 ?

@Mark that is the same setting, and I had seen that thread but I didn't notice that answer because it was buried. But also the original question is for tabs specifically not the list on the open editors panel.

You can change the label format of the open editors panel by editing customLabels.patterns (Workbench > Editor > Custom Labels: Patterns) in settings. It does not have pre-existing format options similar to tabs, and changing the aforementioned setting also changes the formatting for tabs and other locations file labels are displayed.
For a project with many index files you may want to add a rule such as the following
**/index.tsx -> ${dirname}/index.tsx
Or to capture all index file types
**/index** -> ${dirname}/index.${extname}
I added a couple more rules for 'Component' and 'styles' files.

If you change to custom labels, you may want to also edit the tab label format so that it does now show duplicated info. You can change the tab label (Workbench > Editor: Label Format) to 'default' to show only the custom label, versus 'short' which also shows directory.
